# Http://..../mywebservice?wsdl throws exception using Axis2

Tags: java, wsdl, apache-axis

I am learning how to write Webservices in Java using JDK7, AXIS 2.

I copied a very simple HelloWorld example.

```
    package example;

            import javax.jws.WebMethod;
            import javax.jws.WebService;
            import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;


            @WebService()
            public class HelloWorld implements IHelloWorld {
                @WebMethod
              public String sayHelloWorldFrom(String from) {
                String result = "Hello, world, from " + from;
                System.out.println(result);
                return result;
              }

                public static void main(String[] argv) {
                    Object implementor = new HelloWorld();
                    String address = "http://localhost:9001/HelloWorld";
                    Endpoint.publish(address, implementor);
                }
            }
```

My services XML looks like:

```
            <serviceGroup>
                <service name="HelloWorld" targetNamespace="http://example">
                    <Description>Hi</Description>
                    <parameter name="ServiceClass" locked="false">example.HelloWorld</parameter>
                    <operation name="*">
                        <messageReceiver class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
                    </operation>
                </service>
            </serviceGroup>
```

When I attempt to look at the WSDL using

```
    http://localhost:9001/services/HelloWorldService?wsdl
```

I see:
[image]
What is the problem?

-- Thank you

Answer (score 0):

PS: your error message screenshot is too small. But i can decipher something with IndexOutOfBoundException. I think i had that when i was calling my Webservice the wrong way (but not sure).

Anyway, since you use axis2, could you simply look at

```
http://localhost:9001/axis2/services/listServices
```

to see if your service is listed?
I think your Service is HelloWorld, not HelloWorldService.

Comment: I discovered I was developing the Axis2 application incorrectly. I should have developed as an .aar application and deployed to the services directory in the Axis2.war file. The Axis2.war file is available at [link](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/download.cgi). Either download the Binary or the WAR file.